# Maven - Share classes between child projects /parent -and child project

Tags: java, maven, class, import, share

I have a maven project with a parent and a child project. If necessary I could make another child project. One project has to use the class of the other project, but right now it doesn't have any acmes to it.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then one child project declares a Maven dependency (a `<dependency>` in the `pom.xml`) on the other and uses the class.